# Revert NVIDIA driver on low-graphics mode

Tags: graphics

I wanted to update the graphics driver on a Ubuntu laptop so I went to the Additional Drivers menu and selected the newest driver to install (the GPU is an NVIDIA GTX 1050 TI). Now, when I start the laptop, it tells me that the laptop is running on low-graphics mode and I can't get to the desktop. How do I reinstall the old driver to get back to where I was before?